# TP-Link TG-3468 ethernet adapter limits my connection speed to 100Mbps

Tags: ethernet, internet-connection, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet, internet-speed

I have 200Mbps speed connection, but the motherboard ethernet port doesn't allow more than 100Mbps. I bought the TP-Link TG-3468 ethernet adapter, but it still limiting my connection.

In network settings the link speed is 100/100Mbps (see image). Driver is updated, and I checked my internet speed connection in my cellphone and is 200Mbps.

Does anyone understand what is happening here and why can’t I get 200Mbps?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the “MB” mean here: “…but the MB ethernet port…” Motherboard? MacBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you can't transmit more than 100Mb/s over a 100baseT connection.

There are two possible bottlenecks:

1. Your router doesn't support Gigabit ethernet on its ports
2. Your cable doesn't support 1000baseT or is damaged

You might check your routers specification first.
If your router supports gigabit ethernet on its LAN ports without any doubt, you need to check your cabling.

Note that for a gigabit connection you need at least a CAT 5e cable with a maximum length of 100m.